# Create objects dynamically with loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, loops, dynamic

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm basically trying to build an OOP solution to dynamically generate a lot of objects based on a class and then to be able to run methods associated to each object via the class methods.

Below is my un-dynamic code.

```
// Create videoObject class
function videoObject(videoTag, videoNum){
    this.videoTag = videoTag;
    this.videoNum = videoNum;
    this.videoTagHref = videoTag.attr("href");
    this.videoId = function(videoTag){
    };
    this.addAttrId = function(videoNum){
    };
    this.printObjectInfo = function(videoId){
    };
    this.embedVideo = function(videoId, videoTag, videoNum){
    };
    this.buildControls = function(videoTag){
    };
};

// Manually create two objects and run class methods
var newVideo1 = new videoObject($('.yt-player-0'), 0);
newVideo1.videoId();
newVideo1.addAttrId();
newVideo1.embedVideo();
newVideo1.buildControls();

var newVideo2 = new videoObject($('.yt-player-1'), 1);
newVideo2.videoId();
newVideo2.addAttrId();
newVideo2.embedVideo();
newVideo2.buildControls();

// I want to somehow create newVideo1 and newVideo2 dynamically inside a loop like below
var length = $('.yt-player').length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

}
```

Any help you guys could give me would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: So why don't you put them inside the loop?

Comment: I was under the impression I couldn't create variables like these dynamically. I'm a little unsure where to start.

Comment: If you need to store a reference to an object store it in a array or object. For example `videos['ht-player-0'] = new VideoObject();`

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for your response. Would you mind elaborating, I'm not too sure how to implement this. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this (untested):

```
// Create videoObject class
function videoObject(videoTag, videoNum){
    this.videoTag = videoTag;
    this.videoNum = videoNum;
    this.videoTagHref = videoTag.attr("href");
    this.videoId = function(videoTag){
    };
    this.addAttrId = function(videoNum){
    };
    this.printObjectInfo = function(videoId){
    };
    this.embedVideo = function(videoId, videoTag, videoNum){
    };
    this.buildControls = function(videoTag){
    };
    // call these methods in your constructor instead of repeatedly from elsewhere
    this.videoId();
    this.addAttrId();
    this.embedVideo();
    this.buildControls();
    // send back a reference to this newly created video object to the loop
    return this;
};

// create an array of video object references
var videoObjectReferences = [];
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    // building ten video objects here, with ids of: yt-player-0, yt-player-1, etc.
    // build a selector to reference them via id, not by class with a dot as you have in your question
    var sel = String("#yt-player-" + i);
    // create the object and store a reference to the video object so you can do something with it later
    var newVid = new videoObject($(sel), i);
    // build list of references
    videoObjectReferences.push(newVid);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
var videos = [2]; 
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   videos[i] = new videoObject($('.yt-player-0'), 0);
   /*Extra method calls here*/ 
}
```

If you always want to initialize your object with those extra method calls, you may want to consider having your object constructor handle that for you. Then your client code would be much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I couldn't get this to work but @itsmikem's answer worked well.

Comment: lol sorry i had some java syntax in there. that is why it probably didnt work. Made the edit now.